# Combine multiple dataframes of unequal length into a new dataframe

Tags: r, cbind

I want to combine multiple dataframes of **unequal length** into a new dataframe that has `NA` values for empty rows.

e.g.  df1

```
A
1
2
3
4
5

df2
B
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Desired output

```
df3
A  B
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
5  5
NA 6
```

I tired a `cbind()` but that gives me an error.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = 1:5)
df1$id <- row.names(df1)
df2 <- data.frame(B = 1:6)
df2$id <- row.names(df2)
merge(df1, df2, all = T, by = "id")
  id  A B
1  1  1 1
2  2  2 2
3  3  3 3
4  4  4 4
5  5  5 5
6  6 NA 6
```

For situations like this, it is useful to familiarize yourself with [all the different kinds of joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right) that you can do.

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you have recommendations for a thread on joins ?

Comment: @Rn00b I have edited my answer to give you a link. If this answers your question, feel free to accept this answer. If you find it particularly helpful, you can also upvote it.